# Qt remove action from QMenu to add it again later

Tags: c++, qt

I need to remove actions from a `QMenu`, but I need to add them later.

The problem is that whan I re-add them, they dont appear (probably because the actions are deleted when I remove them from the Menu).

How can I do this?

Note that hiding/disabling, etc is not suitable for me, I really need to remove them

Answer (score 3):

You don't say precisely how you create/add/remove the actions from the `QMenu` so I can't comment on what you're currently doing, but... you should be able to create/manage some of the actions yourself and then use the [`QWidget::addAction(QAction *)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addAction) overload -- it *doesn't* assume ownership of the `QAction` passed as a parameter.

```
QMenu menu;
QAction action_I_Want_to_manage("Save...");
menu.addAction("File...");
menu.addAction(&action_I_Want_to_manage);
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());

/*
 * Remove the action temporarily...
 */
menu.removeAction(&action_I_Want_to_manage);
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());

/*
 * ...stick it back in.
 */
menu.addAction(&action_I_Want_to_manage);
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Onde I remove the action, it disappears and is never rendered again. I think it is deleted and becomes a dangling pointer

Comment: If the code above doesn't work then there's something else going on.  It sounds as if your `QAction` is going out of scope or something similar.  If you can edit your question to include your actual code then I'll take a look.